# how to create changelog accordion using angular meterial design

Tags: angular, angular-material, markdown

I wanted to display all the version from a markdown file in an accordion using angular material design. When user clicks on the version header it should expand and display all the changes under that particular version.

Only 5 versions should be displayed by default, other versions will be under pagination

I've no idea on how to implement such a feature,

Please help me with some sample project.

Below is my html file,

```
<p><a name="UNRELEASED"></a></p>
<h1 id="unreleased">UNRELEASED</h1>
<h3 id="bug-fixes">Bug Fixes</h3>
<ul>
<li>adding missing script files 0181341</li>
</ul>
<h3 id="features">Features</h3>
<ul>
<li>add subdomain and configure routing 689a440</li>
</ul>
<p><a name="v7.7.0"></a></p>
<h3 id="features">Features</h3>
<ul><li><strong>footer:</strong> update component <a href="">754</a> 29a14f2</li></ul>
```

from the above html, Accordion title should have the `UNRELEASED` & `v7.7.0`

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: [Something like this ?](https://material.angular.io/components/expansion/overview)

Comment: yes, but I wanted to strip the html from a markdown file

Comment: You can try what the docs does for parsing through Markdown files as seen in this file: https://github.com/angular/material.angular.io/blob/master/src/app/shared/doc-viewer/doc-viewer.ts (EDIT: Basically it uses the Angular CDK portals feature to dynamically render the examples in the documentation. There's also HTML comments in the Markdown docs which gets replaced by the file with the dynamically generated component.)